# C# Need explanation on things involving variables apart of a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So it says that this:

```
public int HoursWorked { get; set; }
```

is the equivalent to...

```
private int hWorked;
public int HoursWorked
{
    get
    {
        return hWorked;
    }
    set
    {
        hWorked = value;
    }
}
```

I have two questions...

1. How does doing the easier command that simply calls "HoursWorked" bring "hWorked" into it?
2. I also don't fully understand what the value of the "value" is meant to be

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: For `public int HoursWorked { get; set; }`, the C# compiler creates a private variable behind the scenes.  It's not called hWorked; it contains characters that are illegal to use in ordinary code to prevent any possibility of name clashes.

Comment: See documentation for [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

Comment: this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) could be helpful to read through

Comment: `value` is the value that the user assigns to the property, as in `HoursWorked = 40`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why don't you write an answer? Why do you answer in comment?

Comment: @KOB: Because this is already well-covered in the C# specification and elsewhere.  The illegal characters are not a well-known fact, but it's not necessary to know that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, some terminology: 
`HoursWorked` is a *property*. `hWorked` is a *field*.

The first example is called an *auto-implemented property*. In that case, the compiler generates a private backing field that's invisible to you.

`value` is a C# language keyword. It is the value that's passed in when you set the property. You can't change it, only assign it. So if you assign `HoursWorked = 10;`, `value` is equal to 10.

In general, if you don't need any additional logic in to your property (for example, validation of allowed values), you should just use an auto-implemented property. It's cleaner, easier to read, and easier to maintain.

Comment: It would be nice to add that `value` is a special keyword that is automatically created that holds the value assigned to the property. In particular I think that the "keyword" part is missing from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**MSDN**

> Properties combine aspects of both fields and methods. To the user of
>   an object, a property appears to be a field, accessing the property
>   requires the same syntax. To the implementer of a class, a property is
>   one or two code blocks, representing a get accessor and/or a set
>   accessor. The code block for the get accessor is executed when the
>   property is read; the code block for the set accessor is executed when
>   the property is assigned a new value. A property without a set
>   accessor is considered read-only. A property without a get accessor is
>   considered write-only. A property that has both accessors is
>   read-write.

```
private int hWorked; // the name field. It will be used internally to hold to value.
public int HoursWorked // the Name property. User will use with object of class.
{
    get
    {
        return hWorked;
    }
    set
    {
        hWorked = value; //  "value" is the actual value (here int) which is assigned by user while accessing this property from somewhere in other class or same class.
    }
}
```

So,  `HoursWorked` is a property. `hWorked` is a field.

**1. How does doing the easier command that simply calls "HoursWorked" bring "hWorked" into it?**

It is called auto-implemented property and there is one invisible backing field generated by compiler.

**2. I also don't fully understand what the value of the "value" is meant to be**

"value" is the actual value (here int) which user assigns / sets. e.g.: user assigns `HoursWorked = 50;` then `value = 50` as well.

check [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) for more details.

Comment: `"value" is the actual value (here int) which is assigned by user while accessing this property from somewhere in other class or same class.` - that's just confusing.